# How to use Java constantns as a parameter in a Struts 2 OGNL tag

Tags: tags, struts2, ognl

I am ussing  to recover a property from an object User in the session. The following expression works correctly:

```
<s:property value="#session.ATRB_SESSION_USER.getAttribute('ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME')"/>
```

but those strings ATRB_SESSION_USER and ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME are constatns defined in a class. How can I use the constant instead of the string? I'd like to do something like this

```
<s:property value="#session.<%=Constants.ATRB_SESSION_USER%>.getAttribute(<%=Constants.ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME%>)"/>
```

Anyone knows how can I do that?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @class@field OGNL syntax to refer to static fields. The class name in @class should be fully qualified.

Comment: So something like this should work?
<s:if test="#session.@com.spb.mvc.util.Constants@.ATRB_SESSION_USER != null ">